# How to hide a Recyclerview Item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview like this:

[image]

The distance between all items is 15dp. Except for the first item, I want to check the left and right distances on other items and hide that item if it is less than 15 dp. How can I do that?

Thank you!

Item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/intervalCard"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            tools:text="99" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dateIndicator"
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@color/ripple_gray" />


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter.kt

```
class TimeIntervalAdapter(
    private val data: List<String>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TimeIntervalAdapter.ItemHolder>() {

    private val items: MutableList<TimeIntervalItem>

    init {
        this.items = ArrayList()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.time_interval_item, parent, false)
        return ItemHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemTitle.text = data[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

    inner class ItemHolder
    internal constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val itemTitle: MaterialTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle)
    }
}
```

LayoutManager.kt - for set dynamic distance to items -

```
class SpanningLinearLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {}
    constructor(context: Context?, orientation: Int, reverseLayout: Boolean) : super(
        context,
        orientation,
        reverseLayout
    ) {
    }

    constructor(
        context: Context?,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttr: Int,
        defStyleRes: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
    }

    override fun generateDefaultLayoutParams(): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        return spanLayoutSize(super.generateDefaultLayoutParams())
    }

    override fun generateLayoutParams(c: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        return spanLayoutSize(super.generateLayoutParams(c, attrs))
    }

    override fun generateLayoutParams(lp: ViewGroup.LayoutParams): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        return spanLayoutSize(super.generateLayoutParams(lp))
    }

    override fun checkLayoutParams(lp: RecyclerView.LayoutParams): Boolean {
        return super.checkLayoutParams(lp)
    }

    private fun spanLayoutSize(layoutParams: RecyclerView.LayoutParams): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            layoutParams.width = horizontalSpace.roundToInt()
        }
        return layoutParams
    }

    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun canScrollHorizontally(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    var horizontalSpace: Double = 0.0
        get() {
            return if (field > 1440) (timelineWidth * 60.0 * 24.0) / (field)
            else (timelineWidth * 60.0) / (field)
        }
    var timelineWidth: Int = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide view for start position in `onBindViewHolder` method of Adapter

Example code:

```
   if(position == 0){
       holder.viewBefore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }else{
       holder.viewBefore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
```

`viewBefore` is your view name that you want to hide or visible.

Comment: Thanks but how can I check distance between items? I want to hide if right and left distance less than 15dp

Comment: Why you are not adding static 15dp width view before item?

Comment: Because its dynamic. Distance can be 20 or 25dp

Comment: Okay, Can you please add your item xml code and Adapter code in question for better understanding of problem?

Comment: Sure, I added now